# <pre> tag in HTML with fixed width

Tags: html, css, tags

I'm using the `<pre>` tag to display preformatted text (including line breaks, spaces and tabs etc.) But large lines without line-breaks are shown in one line and a scroll bar is added.

I want to limit the width of the `<pre>` tag (such that large lines are broken up to come to new lines and no scroll is required. Is this possible or is there some other tag that I can use?

Code is something like:

```
$.post("contr.php", q1, function(data) {
    $("#el_text").html("< pre>"+data+"< /pre>");
});
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

An exhaustive way of supporting it in almost all browsers:

```
pre {
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, supported since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera */
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* CSS3 - Text module (Candidate Recommendation) http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#white-space */
    word-wrap: break-word; /* IE 5.5+ */
}
```

I had the same problem not long ago and had found the solution here:
http://codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=43293

Comment: From W3 Schools, white-space is CSS 1 while word-wrap is CSS 3.

Answer (score 22):

```
pre{
    white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```

..does what you want in Firefox and Chrome - wraps the lines but preserves whitespace. But unfortunately IE doesn't seem to support it (although I haven't looked in IE8 yet).

Edit: IE8 [supports it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531182%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If space is being allocated to the right of the  block even after doing what Karim said
Then maybe you have enclosed  inside .

Table tag allocates space for the entire pre string even when the content may be word wrapped This leads to blank areas on right of pre block

In this case replace  with some other tag, like div or paragraph